# nilradical of a quotient ring

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $R$ be a commutative ring. The $\textbf{radical}$ of an ideal $I$ or $R$ is defined as

$\hspace{3cm} \sqrt{I} := \{x\in R : x^n\in I \hspace{1mm}\text{ for some }\hspace{1mm} n>0 \}$.

How do I show that $R/\sqrt{I}$ has trivial nilradical? The nilradical of a ring is the set of all its nilpotent elements.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $x \in R$ and $x+\sqrt{I} \in R/\sqrt{I}$ is nilpotent. Then $(x+\sqrt{I})^n = 0$ in $R/\sqrt{I}$ for some $n$, which is the same as saying that $x^n \in \sqrt{I}$. But by definition of $\sqrt{I}$, we then have $(x^n)^m \in I$ for some $m$. So $x^{mn} \in I$. In other words, some power of $x$ belongs to $I$. Now what does this say about $x$?

Comment: That means that $x\in \sqrt{I}$. But what does that lead to?

Comment: Well, you started by saying that $x+\sqrt{I}$ is nilpotent and you want to show that $x+\sqrt{I}$ is zero...

Comment: Oh, then $x=0$. I see. So the only nilpotent element is zero. Done. Thanks!